# ValueError: operand '!=' not supported for string comparison

Tags: python, vaex

I want to compare value with string

**i did**

```
df = df[df.s1 != 'NON eq']
```

I was gotting this error **ValueError: operand '!=' not supported for string comparison**

Comment: Which version of vaex do you have? I believe this is fixed in the latest release - might be worth updating if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead :

```py
df = df[~(df.s1 == 'NON eq')]
```

I found this solution [here](https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues/601) (seems to be the same problem).

I *cannot* tell what is causing the problem because the error did not reproduce (worked with `!=`) when I tested it (https://replit.com/astroide/vaex-test if you want to see).

Comment: Please explain why is your given code working and the one given in the question does not

Comment: @CoolCoder I've tried to find it, but installation of `vaex` on my computer failed (import error related to a `.so` file not having `____chkstk_darwin` symbol), so I cannot reproduce the error myself.